# How to align text like math formula?

Tags: align, width, textwidth

Code is here:

```
\noindent
\textit{Pf} Let $G(x)=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{x} f(t) d t$. 

By (1), $G^{\prime}(x)=f(x)$, therefore $(G-F)^{\prime}(x)=0 $ $\forall x \in[a, b]$. 

$\Rightarrow$ $(G-F)(x)=const$.

Let $(G-F)(x)=c$ $\forall x \in[a, b]$, then $F(b)-F(a)=G(b)-G(a)=\int_{a}^{b} f(t) d t$.
```

I want to align "L" in "Let" in first line with "B" in "By" in second line. I've tried `\hspace` to generate some blank but didn't work well. (There is no function like "widthof" so I can't generate blank with proper width. ) I know in math environment I could use `&` to align, but I don't know how to do similar things with plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set *Pf* inside a box that has the same width as `\parindent`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[\parindent][l]{\textit{Pf} }Let $G(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t$. 

By (1), $G^\prime(x) = f(x)$, therefore $(G - F)^\prime(x) = 0 ~ \forall x \in[a, b]$. 

$\Rightarrow$ $(G - F)(x) = \mathrm{const}$.

Let $(G - F)(x) = c ~ \forall x \in[a, b]$, then $F(b) - F(a) = G(b) - G(a) = \int_a^b f(t) \mathrm{d}t$. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use the `proof` environment from `amsthm`. I also suggest you to look at the `amsmath` package if you're typesetting mathematics.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}


\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  Let $G(x) =\int_{a}^{x} f(t) \, d t$.
  
  By (1), $G'(x)=f(x)$, therefore $(G-F)'(x) = 0$
  $\forall x \in[a, b]$.
  
  $\implies (G-F)(x) = \text{const}$.

  Let $(G-F)(x)=c$ $\forall x \in[a, b]$, then
  $F(b)-F(a)=G(b)-G(a) = \int_{a}^{b} f(t) \, d t$.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `tabular`environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
        \textit{Pf}& Let $G(x)=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{x} f(t) d t$. \\
    &   By (1), $G^{\prime}(x)=f(x)$, therefore $(G-F)^{\prime}(x)=0 $ $\forall x \in[a, b]$.\\ 
    &   $\Rightarrow$ $(G-F)(x)=const$.\\
    &   Let $(G-F)(x)=c$ $\forall x \in[a, b]$, then $F(b)-F(a)=G(b)-G(a)=\int_{a}^{b} f(t) d t$. 
\end{tabular}   
    
\end{document}
```